# rewrite image paths based on filename

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Right now, Im rewriting the images paths so "images/tnAhF38eS.jpg" is located at "images/tn/tnAhF38eS.jpg" with:

```
RewriteRule ^/images/(t([a-zA-Z0-9]).+\.jpg)$ /images/t${lc:$2|$2}/$1 [L]
```

First char is always "t" and second is lowercase letter or number.

But, I want to add another level based on the uppercase 3rd character so that "images/tnAhF38eS.jpg" is located at "images/tn/A/tnAhF38eS.jpg"

How do I add that?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same trick that you already did with the first path. I am assuming that `${lc:$2|$2}` is a RewriteMap and that you want to do that on the second path name too. I am assuming you are in VirtualHost context too (ala your current rule does something).

```
RewriteRule ^/images/(t([a-zA-Z0-9])([a-zA-Z0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.jpg)$ /images/t${lc:$2|$2}/${lc:$3|$3}/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, your assumptions are all correct. Sorry I didnt mention that, or include the map: "RewriteMap lc int:tolower" Thanks so much for taking the time!!

Comment: Ok, this is probably a st00pid question, but why do you assign 3 characters to variables "[a-zA-Z0-9])([a-zA-Z0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]" when only the next two after the t are needed to define the path?

Comment: I did test it in `.htaccess` and your original rule resulted in an infinite loop (it did match both `t2Asdf` and `t2/Asdf`. Therefore I changed your `.+` to `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` because that seem to be the only valid characters in your filename. Please note that the last `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` are only in the first capture group with the whole filename.

Comment: Ahh..ok! And since I dont want to apply the lc map (my bad for leaving it out) to the 3rd uppercase letter, would I use t${lc:$2|$2}/${$3}/$1 or t${lc:$2|$2}/$3/$1

Comment: The latter one (`t${lc:$2|$2}/$3/$1`). P.S. You can use backticks (`) for in-line code blocks.

Comment: Thanks. And thanks for the code block tip. Didnt know that :)